# Admin consent required with only delegated permissions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

**Tenaants**

- T1 - holds multi-tenant application
- T2 & T3 - clients of the T1 application

**Permissions**

[image: Permissions]

**Enterprise Settings**

T1, T2 & T3 all have enterprise settings on to allow users to install apps with company data

[image: Enterprise Settings]

When I try to authenticate as an user for T2 or T3 I am presented the following message;

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out our application was flagged by Microsoft as being risky. We didn't get any notification and the only way to determine it is if you have access to the audit logs of the service principal on the tenant.

Comment: How did you get Microsoft to remove the risky flag?

Comment: @LiamBolling I am not sure as that was handled outside of my scope of work

Answer (score 2):

1. Enable the [admin consent workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-admin-consent-workflow#enable-the-admin-consent-workflow)  , which gives end users a way to request access to applications that require admin consent.
2. Refer the permissions documentation for the [Microsoft Graph API indicate which permissions](https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference) require admin consent.
3. The app requires assignment. When an application is configured to require assignment for users to be able to sign in, users are not allowed to consent to that application.

   **Azure AD** > **Enterprise apps** > (select app) > **Properties** > **User assignment required?**
4. Please refer [admin consent endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#using-the-admin-consent-endpoint) for more details.

Comment: Thank you Hari, I was able to get a support response and it looks like everything we have setup is correct but the application was flagged as risky.